# Unable to show modal Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

My modal is an angular component the HTML is as follows.

The filename is delete-category-confirmation-dialog.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper-content container-fluid">
    <div bsModal
         #modal1="bs-modal"
         class="modal modal-centered fade"
         role="dialog"
         aria-modal="true"
         aria-labelledby="modal-title"
         tabindex="-1"
         [config]="{ focus: false }">

        <div class="modal-dialog"
             role="document"
             *ngIf="showDeleteCategoryConfirmationDialog"
             [cdkTrapFocus]="showDeleteCategoryConfirmationDialog"
             [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture]="true">

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title">TERMS OF SERVICE</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Terms of service (also known as terms of use and terms and conditions,
                        commonly abbreviated as ToS or TOS and TOU) are rules by which one must agree
                        to abide in order to use a service.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button uxFocusIndicatorOrigin
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-link button-primary"
                            (click)="modal1.hide()"
                            [focusIf]="modal1.isShown"
                            [focusIfDelay]="200">
                        Agree
                    </button>
                    <button uxFocusIndicatorOrigin
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-link button-secondary"
                            (click)="modal1.hide()">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The typescript file is as follows.

delete-category-confirmation-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-category-confirmation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './delete-category-confirmation-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-category-confirmation-dialog.component.css']
})
export class DeleteCategoryConfirmationDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  @Input() showDeleteCategoryConfirmationDialog:boolean;
  ngOnInit(): void {  
  }

}
```

The parent component where this component is placed is in details.component.html

details.component.html

```
<button type="button"  #deleteCategory
(click)="deleteCat = !deleteCat; $event.stopPropagation()"
class="btn btn-icon-with-text btn-link button-secondary">
<ux-icon name="trash"></ux-icon>
</button>
<app-delete-category-confirmation-dialog showDeleteCategoryConfirmationDialog="{{deleteCat}}"></app-delete-category-confirmation-dialog>
```

details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { LiveAnnouncer } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  panelOpen = false;
  width = '300px';
  top = '56px';
  modal = false;
  animate = true;
  @Input() training:string;
  @Input() cat_id:string;
  closeOnExternalClick = false;
  deleteCat:boolean = false;
  modalPanelOpen = false;
  closeOnEscape = true;
  constructor(private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer) { }

  deleteCategory(){
    this.deleteCat = true;
  }
  onOpenChange(isOpen: boolean, originElement: HTMLElement): void {
    this.announce(isOpen);

    if (!isOpen) {
        originElement.focus();
    }
}
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  announce(isOpen: boolean): void {
    this._liveAnnouncer.announce(`Side panel ${isOpen ? 'opened' : 'closed'}.`);
}
}
```

I am still unable to launch the dialog when the button is clicked.

Comment: what modal/UI library are you using? looks like pure bootstrap to me. In that case, you have to call ```modal1.show()``` somewhere. the ```*ngIf="showDeleteCategoryConfirmationDialog"``` is not responsible for showing/hiding the modal.

Comment: So how do I call that from the parent?

Comment: Hi @VinayJoseph did the answer helped you and resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [ngx-bootstrap Modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/1.9.1/#/modals) the approach you are following to open the modal is incorrect. Try below code

You need to inject the `BsModalService` into the constructor of component from which you want to open the modal and you need to call `.show(<Your Modal Component>)` on `BsModalService`

### Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-5cbkuy?file=app/modal.component.ts)

So in your Details component typescript file, needs below changes

```
...

import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { ModalComponent } from '</path/to/file/ModalComponent>'

...

export class DetailsComponent {
  ...

  constructor(
    private bsModalService: BsModalService,
  ) {}

  ...
  
  openModal(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.bsModalService.show( ModalComponent );
  }
}
```

And in the Details template file

```
<button type="button" #deleteCategory (click)="openModal($event)" class="btn btn-icon-with-text btn-link button-secondary">
```

If you want to send any data to the modal, you can use `BsModalRef` like below

Assign opened modal reference to some property -> Declare a property in Details component like

```
public bsModalRef : BsModalRef;
```

And when opening the Modal

```
this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(<Your Modal Component>);
this.bsModalRef.content.<any property declared in your modal component> = <any value>
```